# hiredis run Sync command from Async Context

Tags: asynchronous, redis, eval, synchronization, hiredis

I'm using the [hiredis C client library](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) to interact with Redis in an async context.

On some point of my workflow I have to make a Sync call to Redis but I'm not being able to get a successful response from Redis.

I'm not sure whether I can **issue a sync command to Redis from an async context** but...

I have something like this

```
redisAsyncContext * redis_ctx;
redisReply * reply;

// ...

reply = redisCommand(&(redis_ctx->c), COMMAND);
```

After `redisCommand` call, my [`reply` is NULL what is documented as an error condition](https://github.com/redis/hiredis#using-replies) and my `redis_ctx->c` is like

```
err    = 0
errstr = '\000' <repeats 127 times>
fd     = 11
flags  = 2
obuf   = "*5\r\n$4\r\nEVAL\r\n$215\r\n\"math.randomseed(tonumber(ARGV[1])) local keys = redis.call('hkeys',KEYS[1]) if #keys == 0 then return nil end local key = keys[math.random(#keys)] local value = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], key) return {key, value}\"\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n$0\r\n\r\n$1\r\n1\r\n"
reader = 0x943730
```

I can't figure out whether the command was issued or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late. I'm not so expert about Redis, but if you need to make a Sync call to Redis, why would you use an AsyncContext?

If you just use redisCommand with a redisContext everything should be fine.

Assuming that variable `ctx` has been declared as

```
redisContext *ctx;
```

you can use `redisCommand` like this:

```
reply = (redisReply *)redisCommand(ctx, "HGET %s %s", hash, key);
```

Comment: My point is whether it is possible to get the `redisContext` (sync) from `redisAsyncContext` (async) and then issue the `redisCommand` (sync).

Comment: Have you tried to use `redisAsyncInitialize`? I'm not sure if this could be useful to what you're trying to do.
Source: [link](https://github.com/redis/hiredis/blob/master/async.c)

Comment: everything is working perfect about the async context/commands, but at some point of my workflow I want to issue a sync command what requires a redis sync context, which is available on the AsyncContext struct. If it was possible to get a sync context from an async one, I could avoid to declare another context